# Why does the Python Bottle micro-framework faq say it is typically for small websites and prototypes?

Tags: scalability, bottle, web-frameworks

From the documentation (http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/faq.html):

> Is bottle suitable for complex applications?
>
> Bottle is a micro framework designed for prototyping and building
>   small web applications and services. It stays out of your way and
>   allows you to get things done fast, but misses some advanced features
>   and ready-to-use solutions found in other frameworks (MVC, ORM, form
>   validation, scaffolding, XML-RPC). Although it is possible to add
>   these features and build complex applications with Bottle, you should
>   consider using a full-stack Web framework like pylons or paste
>   instead.

What I do not understand is why is Bottle for small websites?  Is it because the lack of out of the box tools?  Is there something wrong with running big sites, as in the code for the Bottle framework isn't as "fast" or optimized, as Flask, for example?

It goes on to say it is possible create a complex website in Bottle, but then says to use a full-stack Web framework,

> Although it is possible to add these features and build complex
>   applications with Bottle, you should consider using a full-stack Web 
>   framework like pylons or paste instead.

Why?

I do not understand why it cannot be used for large applications vs. something like Flask (that can be).  What is it that breaks down in Bottle that wouldn't in another Framework?  Is it because it is only one file?

Comment: I think the Bottle writer is trying to imply that big sites need ORM for database access, forms, logins, and other fancy functionality that comes with running a big site with user accounts.

Comment: Well, I like to build all that myself, so I guess Bottle is good for me.  I thought the author was saying the framework would somehow break for some unknown reason, like it "couldn't take it anymore" and hose up.

Comment: It tells you why: it *misses some advanced features and ready-to-use solutions found in other frameworks (MVC, ORM, form validation, scaffolding, XML-RPC).*. Those reasons are what the other frameworks include, which is why it recommends you consider using them. This information is stated quite clearly without any ambiguity; I'm not sure why there's a need to ask for any more clarification. The others have the functionality implemented and tested already, while anything you add yourself to Bottle has not been.